# Piping/streaming file from memory to bucket in Firebase/GCS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to generate multiple documents and pack them together to a zip and upload it to Google Cloud Storage via Firebase (using default bucket).

So far:

- generating multiple documents **works**
- packing them together **doesn't work** (I get empty zip and I'm using [ArchiverJS](https://www.archiverjs.com/))
- uploading to the bucket (it's just empty) **works**

Seems like to upload a file I need to save it to temporary folder within Firebase Function, but I can't find any solution how to empty it after using. So I wanted to use streams, but then I was warned that it's a bad idea because checksum and such.

On the other hand [`.save()` function](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) let's save arbitrary data. It was specifically requested [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1179#issuecomment-199801543), but really doesn't seem to work (at least for me).

Also, ArchiverJS seems to also [let use of streams](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/216).

So, theoretically, it should all work nicely. But it's not so I hope someone else knows better.

```
const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var archiver = require('archiver')
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../servicekey.json")
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "myName.appspot.com"
})
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket()

const {
  convertCSVtoJSON,
  generateDocuments,
  generateDocx,
  isCorrectTemplateFileType
} = require('./generateServices')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if(!isCorrectTemplateFileType(req.files.template))
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Wrong file type. Please provide .docx file.'
      })

    const template = req.files.template.data
    const data = await convertCSVtoJSON(req.files.data1)

    let zip = archiver('zip')
    
    zip.on('warning', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });

    zip.on('error', function(err) {
      res.status(500).send({error: err.message})
    });

    zip.on('entry', function(ars) {
      // console.log(ars)
    });

    zip.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', zip.pointer())
    });

    // res.attachment('archive-name.zip')
  
    // zip.pipe(output)
    // zip.pipe(res)
    
    data.forEach((docData, index) => {
      let buff = generateDocx(template, docData, 'title')
      zip.append(buff, { name: `${index}.docx` })
    })

    zip.finalize()

    console.log(zip)
    const file = bucket.file("pliki.zip") // nazwa do zmiany
    file.save(zip, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("cool");
      } else {
        console.log("error " + err);
      }
    });

    res.sendStatus(201)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send(error)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: For anyone who runs into this issue, I recommend just switching over to using firebase storage. It's a lot less of a headache and very quick to set up.